# Sincronizar Banco de Dados Local a partir de servidor remoto no IONIC

Tags: mysql, angularjs, apache-cordova, sqlite, ionic

Pessoal como fazer para atualizar um banco de dados em uma aplicação mobile toda vez que o banco de dados remoto for atualizado.

Por exemplo eu tenho uma aplicaçao em ionic, e pra ficar mais rápido eu uso o banco de dados de consulta de contatos localmente no entanto esses dados são atualizados remotamente, dessa maneira eu preciso atualizar o banco local da aplicação mobile.

Eu tenho duas formas de banco de dados Local, uma é carregando um arquivo JSON:

```
$http.get('js/dados.json').then(function(response) {
 angular.forEach(response.data, function(items) {
  $scope.total = items.length;
  for (i=0; i < $scope.limite; i++) {
    $scope.chats.push(items[i]);
  }
 });
}
```

Em outro exemplo eu carrego os dados de um SQLite:

```
$scope.select = function(lastname) {
    var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people WHERE lastname = ?";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [lastname]).then(function(res) {
        if(res.rows.length > 0) {
            console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(0).firstname + " " + res.rows.item(0).lastname);
        } else {
            console.log("No results found");
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/

Alguém teria alguma solução para isso.

Comment: Estou com a mesma dúvida, vou enquanto pesquiso vou acompanhar respostas aqui!

Answer (score 1):

Pergunta antiga, mas espero que esta resposta sirva para os demais googlers.

Vou dar um exemplo de como fazer. (código não testado!)

Crie a factory abaixo: ela armazena seus contatos em memória, na variável `atuais` que só é acessivel por meio da função `getContatos()`

```
.factory('Contato',  function () {

   var atuais = { last: 0, contatos: {} };

   var ContatoFactory = {

        setContatos: function(novos) {   
            var processed = 0;
            if (isPresent(novos)) {
                if (atuais.last<novos.last) {
                    if (isPresent(novos.contatos)) {
                        atuais.last = novos.last;

                        for (var key in novos.contatos) {
                            if (!atuais.contatos[key]) atuais.contatos[key] = {};
                            angular.copy(novos.contatos[key],  atuais.contatos[key]);
                            processed++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('setContatos: falhou: novos.contatos = ' + novos.contatos);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('setContatos: falhou: atuais.last [' + atuais.last + '] >= novos.last [' + novos.last + ']');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('setContatos: nenhum contato novo para processar');
            }
            console.log('setContatos: ', processed, ' contatos processados');
        },
        getContatos: function() {
            console.log('getContatos: ' + angular.toJson(atuais) );
            return angular.copy(atuais);
        },
        clearContatos: function() {
            angular.copy({ last:0, contatos: {} }, atuais);
            console.log('clearContatos: ' + angular.toJson(atuais) );
        },
        persistirContatos: function() {
            //seu código aqui para salvar no SQLite ou LocalStorage
            //exemplo:
            localStorage.setItem('meusContatos', angular.toJson(atuais) );
        }
   };
   return ContatoFactory;
})
```

Em algum lugar do seu código, você vai recuperar os contatos do backend via AJAX (não esqueça de injetar sua Factory para poder usá-la):

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://meuServidor.com/contatos?last=' + lastPosixUpdate
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
      Contato.setContato(response);  // response => { last: <POSIX_DATE>, contatos: { key1: {nome: 'abc', fone: '123' },  key2: {nome: 'xyz', fone: '456'}, ... }  }    
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('Ajax falhou');
  });
```

Depois você pode recuperar seus contatos em qualquer controller de sua App:

`$scope.contatos = Contato.getContatos();`

Da mesma maneira você pode persistir seus dados quando achar conveniente:

`Contato.persistirContatos();`

Veja que o backend manda um JSON assim:

```
{ last: <POSIX_DATE>, contatos: { key1: {nome: 'abc', fone: '123' },  key2: {nome: 'xyz', fone: '456'}, ... }  }
```

sendo que `last` deve ser um número representando a última alteração executada na tabela de contatos. Assim, a resposta só será processada se houver contatos novos ou alterados.

Da mesma forma,  o `$http.get` envia um querystring last=238274 para sinalizar ao backend a partir de quando ele deseja as atualizações de contato.

Você pode implementar o tal `last` (o que é bom quando a lista de contatos é enorme) ou simplesmente recuperar todos os contatos sempre.

função auxiliar:

```
//retorna true se o objeto existe e é não vazio
function isPresent(obj) {
    return obj && (Object.keys(obj).length!==0);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, explicação muito bem executada e muito importante para todos que necessitam de explicações acerca do assunto, valeu Fernando.